# Sharing an Eclipse workspace between Linux and Windows

Tags: android, linux, windows, eclipse

I've come to use Eclipse to develop for Android on my Windows machine for quite some time now, but more and more I've been booting up into my Ubuntu partition. I honestly love both operating systems as they both have their pros and cons, but I boot into each one randomly. Anyway, I have three partitions on my hard drive. One for Windows 8, one for Ubuntu, and one for shared data (docs, pics, videos). But I would like to seamlessly develop on one OS and then on the other. So, my data partition should be able to hold my workspace, but I don't know if that will ruin or corrupt the .metadata and potentially ruin my projects. Basically my question is... are there any tips or tricks with the Android SDK, AVD, ADT, workspace, or .metadata when using them between two OS's so that it works seamlessly?

Answer (score 5):

In theory, you can use two different installations of Eclipse to manage one shared workspace. However, you could potentially run into problems if you aren't running *exactly* the same version on both sides (or, if you upgrade one side but not the other).

In practice, you are probably better off having separate workspaces on each OS, and then having a shared repository (using Git, for example) to share your code. Not only will that work better, but you'll be using source control too.

Comment: Would a different workspace include a different .metadata as well?

Answer (score 3):

People have tried that before and run into trouble, so please go with the version control solution instead.

The drawback is that only the project contents are shared in the version control system. You will have two completely separate workspaces. So if you change workspace settings, they need to be changed twice (and don't even think about having .metadata under version control, that will have bad side effects).

Please be aware that several settings in Eclipse are available as workspace settings and also as project settings (e.g. the Java compiler version to be used). Make sure that you use the project settings and that you put the contents of the ".settings" sub directory in your projects under version control, because it contains these project settings. So they are in sync between your 2 machines.

Answer (score 0):

I have been sharing workspace between linux and windows for quite some time and I only had minor hiccups.

Here are some of the things to keep in mind, if at all something has gone wrong, and you want to try some quick fix.

- Initially you'll have to point the location of your sdk to the windows or linux path. This would be the first error that can crop up.
- Try a clean build of the project(Project -> Clean -> Clean All Project -> Click OK)
- Check Location Path of the project (Right Click Project -> Click on Resource). If it is loading from an ubuntu path (Eg: /home//Android_Projects), then you'll have to delete the project (Not from disk but from workspace) and import again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do you resolve the fact that Windows and Linux want to use a different naming convention for paths?  i.e. windows wants to use e.g. c:\Users\michael\Android\... while Linux wants to use /Users/michael/Android/... for the same identical path?