# How can i share an eclipse project files between linux and windows?

Tags: eclipse

We have an eclipse project in windows, but we want to share it between both windows eclipse users and linux eclipse users. However, when a linux user opens the project he has to do two things:

1. We depend on a third party library which is installed in a different directory on windows and linux machine. Therefore the linux user must change the Path Variable, say "LIB" to point to the correct directory on his machine.
2. We use the same Path Variable to generate a couple of other Path Variables, e.g. "$(LIB)\something" and the linux user has to change the backslash to a forward slash.

Is there any smart way to avoid this, other than maintaining two seperate project files?

Comment: 1. You can use NTFS junctions (symbolic links) instead of setting path variables. Both Windows and Linux understand them (but Windows doesn't understand Linux symlinks, so always use native NTFS junctions). Just link all desired libraries directories into project directory and then set all paths relative to the project dir

Comment: Perhaps sharing eclipse project between Linux and Windows isn't a good idea, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189367/sharing-an-eclipse-workspace-between-linux-and-windows. it's probably better to share sources only (using symbolic links or version control) and have two separate projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) that is available both for Linux and for Windows. There you can configure profiles that can be activated separately for different platforms.

For example:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <os>
        <name>Windows XP</name>
        <family>Windows</family>
        <arch>x86</arch>
        <version>5.1.2600</version>
      </os>
    </activation>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

For more details you can check [this page](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).

So the main idea behind this is to store your source code in version control system **without** project configuration files. Project configuration files should be prepared by a tool that runs on each developer's machine after check out.