# Synchroize Eclipse workspace

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, synchronization

I'm searching for a method to synchroize my Eclipse workspace. I have an apache server from [Strato](http://www.strato.de/) with PHP, SQL databeses, FTP and so on. There I want to store my projects. Is there an Eclipse plugin (maybe in conjunction with a web CMS or something else) with which I can synchronize my whole workspace to my other workstations?

Answer (score 1):

Always use project settings instead of workspace preferences. Then use a version control system and check-in your code *and* your project settings.

Sharing a workspace on multiple machines works only by chance. The .metadata is machine specific. So if you have different operating systems, different Eclipse installations, different Java runtimes, you will run into dubious errors.

Found only one [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13189367/44089), but there have been more.

Comment: Is there a VCS which works on a normal apache server only with PHP, Chronejobs or something else?

Comment: If you can install a very reduced number of libs (http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git), you should be able to install git. Git can be used via http protocol then. I have no knowledge about the other VCSs requirements.